# Set other layout parameters imageview

Tags: android, android-imageview, layoutparams

I would like to have an image on android that appears only when I click a button. So I created it in an `onClick` method, and set its ressource and position with the following code :

```
public void createAddButton() {
    //create the image
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    //setting image resource
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.add_16);
    //setting image position : width and height
    imageView.setLayoutParams(
            new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) );
}
```

But this only allows to define width and height of the image. If I want to define other layout parameters (`android:layout_gravity` or `android:marginLeft` for example, what should I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
lp.bottomMargin = ...
lp.leftMargin = ...
lp.rightMargin = ...
lp.topMargin = ...

imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. We can modify the attributes of the layout ? But I have two questions : The layout must be a linear layout ? And, concerning the modification of the attribute, aren't there setters for that allow to do that "properly" ?

Comment: Can be every subclass of MarginLayoutParams see docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html and they are exposed as fields so you don't have setters methods

Comment: I have another question : as we are defining the linear layout parameters, should we create the linear layout programmatically too, instead of calling the method setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) ?

Comment: yes you can: LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);  ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); and then add your params

Comment: Ok, but if I already have a view activity_main in which I have a layout, how canI tell I want to create the imageView in this layout ? I mean there is no method like image.setLayout()...

Comment: If you want to create your layout programmatically do as in previous comment, then: ll.addView(imageview) or if yout layout.xml has an id, you can fetch your LinearLayout with findViewById(..) and then add your imageview

Comment: Actually I have a layout.xml that I want to use. Ok I see thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `LayoutParams` object to access those layout properties as below...

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    params.leftMargin = 10;

    imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: I tried to modify the attributes as you said but apparently it the layout must be a linear one, in order to have a gravity attribute

Comment: The `gravity` attribute is available for `LinearLayout` and `Framelayout`...that's why the system suggests you so.